# How do I determine if a prolog `compund term` has a particular `atom` inside?

Tags: prolog

I want a predicate to tell whether a particular atom (say `x`) appears inside a compound term, however deeply nested.

I tried to read about predicates given at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=manipterm. I think it will involve walking down the compound term using `functor/3` and `../2` recusively. Is there a simpler approach, or some library that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring [cyclic terms](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cyclic), I would use ==/2,compound/1 and arg/3

```erlang
haystack_needle(H,N) :- H==N.
haystack_needle(H,N) :- compound(H),arg(_,H,A),haystack_needle(A,N).
```

haystack_needle/2 will succeed multiple times, then will allow for counting occurrences:

```erlang
?- aggregate(count, haystack_needle(t(a,x,b,[x,x,x]),x), C).
C = 4.
```

Note, the needle does not need to be an atom...

You can use once/1 to tell if needle appears in haystack:

```erlang
?- once(haystack_needle(t(a,x,b,[x,x,x]),x)).
true.

?- once(haystack_needle(t(a,x,b,[x,x,x]),z)).
false.
```

As noted by Paulo, arg/3 could not act appropriately in ISO compliant Prologs.
A portable alternative (with arguments swapped without other purpose than avoiding confusion) could be

```erlang
needle_haystack(N,H) :- N==H.
needle_haystack(N,H) :- H=..[_|As],member(A,As),needle_haystack(N,A).
```

Of course, if member/2 is available :)

Comment: Or instead of `member/2` just using an auxiliary `needle_haystack/3` predicate that iterates the list of arguments. Interesting point, `functor/3` + `arg/3` *may* be faster than `=../2` while also avoiding the creation of a temporary list that will eventually be garbaged collected.

Answer (score 5):

Carlo's elegant answer works on SWI-Prolog but is not portable as the ISO Prolog standard specification for the `arg/3` predicate (which most Prolog systems implement) requires its first argument to be bound to an integer, preventing using it as a backtracable generator of compound term arguments. A more portable alternative would be:

```
haystack_needle(H, N) :-
    H == N.
haystack_needle(H, N) :-
    functor(H, _, A),
    between(1, A, I),
    arg(I, H, A),
    haystack_needle(A, N).
```

The `between/3` predicate is not specified in the ISO Prolog standard but it's a de facto standard predicate usually provided as either a built-in predicate or a library predicate.